# Strange text under my WordPress Blog

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to get rid of some strange text appearing under my WordPress blog, I have check Wordpress support and googled about it but nothing. I tried changing the Theme of the blog too, but to no avail. The Address to my blog is abuango.net. I will be glad if you can guide me to solving this issue...

I am using the Foghorn Theme, below is a preview of the strange text:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you got infected. Either by a plugin, theme, outdated WordPress installation, or insecure form somewhere on the website. Try running WordPress exploit scanner: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exploit-scanner/

Comment: Please put the page to look if there is some html tag break. And yes, seems spam comments. Are you using [http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet) ?

Comment: @NomikOS : I am using Akismet and it says all is fine, I am currently trying some Exploit and Virus scanners to see if they will work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been hacked. Read **[Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)** for advice.

The most important part is: You have to find the infection point. If you don't know this … it will happen again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it using WordDefence (http://www.wordfence.com), my General Template was modified, the plugin showed a side by side comparison of the original and the modified file and gave an option to restore original.  i will now proceed to changing all my passwords. Thanks all